# How can I avoid activating all the methods on a class?

Tags: java

I am trying to make an ArrayList which handles different GUI components.
This class should have methods and some of them wouldn't apply to all of the components so i tried to  use a conditional buy it seems impossible to solve it that way.

Could you point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

code:

```
    public class ArrGUI
    {
    private ArrayList <JLabel>  lab;
    private ArrayList <JButton> but;
        //...
    final int t;

    public ArrGUI(JLabel x){
    lab = new ArrayList <JLabel> ();
    t=0;}
    //... more constructors with different paramenters different t values
    //common methods of array list

    if(tipo==0)
    {
    public void VisibleSI() {
    for (JLabel i: lab) i.setVisible(true);}

    public void VisibleNO() {
    for (JLabel i: lab) i.setVisible(false);}
    //...
```

edit: i solved my problem this way. to access any other method i would use the obtener method.
thanks for the help.

```
    public class ArregloGUI
    {
private ArrayList <Component> lab;

public ArregloGUI(Component x){
lab = new ArrayList <Component> ();}

//Operaciones
public void adicionar(Component x) {
    lab.add(x);}

public int tamaño() {
    return lab.size();}

public Component obtener(int i) {
    return lab.get(i);}

public void eliminarAlFinal() {
    if (tamaño() > 0)   lab.remove(tamaño()-1);}

public void reinicializarArreglo() {
    if (tamaño() > 0)   lab.clear();}

public void ubicar(int i, int x, int y, int xx, int yy){
    obtener(i).setBounds(x,y,xx,yy);}
    }
```

Comment: This isn't clear. Please give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: This is where you'd create two or more `interfaces` to your class with logical separation. For more info read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: Thanks i will check interfaces, i read a bit but i couldn't explain how to use it here. I made a solution to this by making an ArrayList of `Component`, and instanciating it separatly for each GUI element. At least it works for what i am doing, and sorry i didnt made it so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a certain method is available to be called on an object is determined statically in Java. It may not depend on data stored in the object.

You could let the method throw an `IllegalStateException` if it is called when it should not. For example:

```
public void VisibleSI() {
    if (tipo != 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    for (JLabel i: lab) i.setVisible(true);
}
```

However, a better approach is to define different classes for the different cases.

Comment: You are right. Because i would be creating a BIG class for nothing (and might be consuming memory as well). However i managed to solve my problem by replacing the GUI components, by a COMPONENT class. It is working like charm until now. (the class is replaced with a single Component arraylist field and i don't need the specific methods sice i can access with a public Component method returning `lab.get(i); `.
I am creating an instance of this class for each component type for better results.